# How to trigger an event sending info to GA 4 in client side, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

**Hello Everyone**,

I want to be able to trigger events and sending info to `Google Analytics 4` (GA4), using javascript.
Following  this link [developer google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?visit_id=638004880768423092-3564517995&rd=1&client_type=gtm) I am able to create tags and triggers but, I am obligated to use [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) for every single client we have, since for every client we have a separate domain so I need to add every domain in [tag assistant](https://tagassistant.google.com/) and create the tags and triggers.
[image]

If I have for example 100 clients to manage, then is it rational to do all repetitive procedures for all of them, including the same tags and triggers?
In fact I am searching to find a method I can do once and apply them for all clients.

In tag assistant, after I click a button which triggers a tag and event I have
[image]

having these info as datalayer.push can I simplify my tasks? for example a piece of java script which may do the same push to datalayer?

I have even created another container to test if I could have access to the previous tags and triggers, but it just open a new "**Empty workspace**" like the following photo:
[image]

**Thanks**

Comment: So your role are more like website provider or agency. You want to create the tag and trigger in multiple GTM container with the same tag and trigger? I assume there are different GTM container and different GA4 data stream to send right?

Comment: yes. I mean that is not going to be just one tag and a trigger. the difficulty would be this. I would like to manage everything in coding part because it is not easy to create all repetitive tag and triggers for all clients.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution could be config a lot of Google Tag Manager container through their API

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2

We used to do something similar. Control multiple `tags` and `triggers` in our platform and deploy all of them to GTM once.

This API let you access all GTM Containers you have access to and create the tag and trigger as you wish.

Be careful with their API rate limit. It is easy to exceed the limit and causing some trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but when I create a new container it gives me a new workspace in tag manager and I do not have access to the tags I have already created for my previous container